# PHP Regex Extracting particular link from body text

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a certain link i.e. https://www.amazon.com/order?id=* where * is an alphanumberic string of variable length eg. https://www.amazon.com/order?id=pbW14792Zs86165 from the body of html text, an example of which is

```
To view your order details, click this link:<br /><a href=https://www.amazon.com/order?id=pbW14792Zs86165>https://www.amazon.com/order?id=pbW14792Zs86165</a><br><br><strong>Amazon</strong><br />Browse millions of products. <a href='https://www.amazon.com'>https://www.amazon.com</a><br /><br />
```

I have tried the following code, but its getting the link alongwith other html tags and more text

```
preg_match("/(?:^|(?<=[,.\s\"\>]))https:\/\/www\.amazon\.com\/order\?id=\S+(?=[\<\"\s,.]|$)/",$message,$matches); echo "$matches[0]<br>";
```

The output I get with this is undesired

```
https://www.amazon.com/order?id=pbW14792Zs86165</a><br><br><strong>Amazon</strong><br
```

How can I modify the code to simply get this particular link and nothing else?

Comment: `\S` matches anything that is not whitespace. Thus, you should replace it with what you would like to match. Perhaps `\w` is better - it matches letters, digits and underscore.

Comment: why not just simply extract the id as id=\w+

Comment: Simply capture the id as \?id=(\w+)

Comment: yes that works perfect, thanks! @MohammadYusufGhazi if you will add it as an answer, I can mark the question as solved

Comment: @HowardRhodes okay. go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply capture the id as \?id=(\w+)